# Finding list object that contains vector element

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors. Is there any way to find list object(s) that contain a particular vector element in the setting below?

**Example data:**

```
> head(mylist)
$ENSG00000049449
[1]   5954 440034

$ENSG00000050327
[1]      7984 102725117

$ENSG00000072195
[1]     29904 100996693

$ENSG00000091262
[1]       368 105369239

$ENSG00000100031
[1]      2678     91227     92086    728441 102724197

$ENSG00000103319
[1]     29904 101930123
```

**Expected output:**

```
>magicalstuff(7984)
[1] "ENSG00000050327"

>magicalstuff(29904)
[1] "ENSG00000072195" "ENSG00000103319"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
names(mylist)[(unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) 29904 %in% x)))]
[1] "ENSG00000072195" "ENSG00000103319"
```

Answer (score 5):

```r
mylist <-
  structure(
    list(
      ENSG00000049449 = c(5954, 440034),
      ENSG00000050327 = c(7984,102725117),
      ENSG00000072195 = c(29904, 100996693),
      ENSG00000091262 = c(368,105369239),
      ENSG00000100031 = c(2678, 91227, 92086, 728441, 102724197),
      ENSG00000103319 = c(29904, 101930123)
    ),
    .Names = c(
      "ENSG00000049449", "ENSG00000050327", "ENSG00000072195",
      "ENSG00000091262", "ENSG00000100031", "ENSG00000103319"
    )
  )

names(mylist[grep("7984", mylist) ])
#> [1] "ENSG00000050327"

names(mylist[grep("29904", mylist) ])
#> [1] "ENSG00000072195" "ENSG00000103319"
```

Comment: Thanks! But apparently, this solution also matches list objects partially matching the vector element. When you look for "7984", it matches list objects that contain "12798492" as well.

Comment: That an easy fix `..grep("^7984$"..`

Answer (score 3):

```
findme <- function(value, object){
names(object)[sapply(object, function(x) value %in% x)]
}
#> findme(2678, mylist)
#[1] "ENSG00000072195"
```

Answer (score 2):

A magical function:

```
magicalstuff <- function(x) {
  ind <- unlist(lapply(mylist, `%in%`, x=x))
  names(mylist)[ind]
}

magicalstuff(7984)
#[1] "ENSG00000050327"
```